# What do shrines do?

Tags: enter-the-gungeon

I found this statue on chamber three. What does it do?

[image: Statue]

Are there other kinds of statues/shrines what do they do?

Comment: I have never played the game, so I don't know if this is accurate, but 99% of the games that I have played with statues like that only have them there for decoration/thematic purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of shrines in the game, each with different effects. I have found the following:

1. 'The only legible text is "...offering..." The rest is blank.'

   - If you use a blank, you'll get a chest.
2. 'A shrine to a prideful bullet angel, now fallen.'

   - You can offer a heart container for additional damage.
3. 'A shrine to a forgotten bullet who laid down his arms...will you?'

   - You can offer a gun at the altar for some hearts.
4. 'A shrine to Icosahedrax, the great arbiter.'

   - You can choose whether or not to roll the bones. Rolling the bones will give you a random buff+debuff.
5. 'A shrine to Shell'tan, ammo elemental.'

   - If you kneel at the altar, you get the status effect "Deal with the devil: The shadows grow darker." This causes all ammo to be refilled, but also increases the players curse by 3.5.
6. A challenge shrine.

   - Activating this shrine will spawn three waves of enemies. Defeating all enemies will give you a chest.
7. A fountain shrine.

   - This shrine will remove all current Curse for a fee. If your curse is 10+, your curse will not be removed.
8. Y.V. Shrine

   - Permanently gives each gun a chance to fire an additional bullet with no ammo cost.
9. Hero Shrine.

   > Found only at the beginning, this shrine can only be activated after you kill the past of the current character. Activating this shrine will set your curse to 9.

Comment: I'll add detail as I find them and figure out what they do.

Comment: The fourth shrine will refill your health if you give it a gun.

Comment: There's a special altar in the second chamber that's addressed in [another question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/261545/how-do-i-use-an-altar).

Comment: The fifth shrine gives you a variety of things, but there's always one buff and one debuff, which can include things like health, ammo, curse, blanks, damage, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you shoot a blank in the room with the statue that has 'The only legible text is " ...offering..." The rest is blank.' You get a Chest.

Answer (score -2):

here you have all the information about the shrines:

http://enterthegungeon.gamepedia.com/Shrines

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged since it's possible the link might change or the page will be deleted at some point. It's much better to include at least a summary of the page here.