# What does the switch inside the fire do?

Tags: enter-the-gungeon

There's a fire in a room and I used my mega douser to put out the fire, I went inside and pressed the action button and I heard something change inside the dungeon, can somebody tell me what it did ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Congratulations, you've unlocked the secret room that will take you to the Oubliette.  It's a secret level between the first and second floors.  Look for a new room on your map.

If you can't find a weapon that fires something wet, you can also roll a water barrel into the room to put the fire out.  This takes a bit more work, but you can import a barrel from another room if you're so inclined.

It takes two keys to unlock the trap door down to the Oubliette, so I hope you saved up!  If not, there's always next time...

Do note that falling down the trap door means you'll leave this level completely, so if you want to, say, kill the boss first for a chance at guns/hegemony credits, do so beforehand.

Comment: Does this button have to be hit each run, or just once total?

Comment: @Powerlord, you've got to put out the fire and hit the switch every run.

Comment: Yeah, I found this out when I tried it. So, of course the one time I opened it, I ended up dying against the Chamber 1 bosses because I kept mistiming dodges while trying to charge a very slow charging gun.

Comment: Just to add on to the answer, as of version 1.0.8 there will always be a water barrel in the fireplace room if you've opened the secret passage on previous runs. (You still have to roll it over to the fireplace though, so be careful while fighting in this room to prevent it from accidentally popping.)